# git apply --3way: don't abort if some hunks fail

Tags: git

## Situation

I have a file called `testing.txt` committed in the repo, with the following contents:

```
First line
```

I'm attempting to apply this patch, which modifies two files, `testing.txt` and `nonexistent.txt`:

```
diff --git a/testing.txt b/testing.txt
index 5e867b1..e5c47f2 100644
--- a/testing.txt
+++ b/testing.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 Non-matching first line
+Second line from patch
diff --git a/nonexistent.txt b/nonexistent.txt
index 9649cde..8aab0eb 100644
--- a/nonexistent.txt
+++ b/nonexistent.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 First line
+Second line from patch
```

using this command:

```
git apply --verbose --3way patch.txt
```

During the execution of the command, the `testing.txt` hunk is successfully applied with a fallback three-way merge:

```
Checking patch testing.txt...
error: while searching for:
Non-matching first line

error: patch failed: testing.txt:1
Falling back to three-way merge...
Applied patch to 'testing.txt' with conflicts.
```

and (as expected) the `nonexistent.txt` hunk fails (because that file doesn't exist):

```
Checking patch nonexistent.txt...
error: nonexistent.txt: does not exist in index
```

## Problem

The entire `apply` command is aborted because the `nonexistent.txt` hunk fails.

The three-way merge for the `testing.txt` hunk is discarded, even though it was successful.

This is stated in the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply):

> For atomicity, `git apply` by default fails the whole patch and does not touch the working tree when some of the hunks do not apply.

## Question

I want the successful `testing.txt` hunk to be applied to the file, not discarded. How can I do this?

In other words, how can I change the `nonexistent.txt` fatal error to a non-fatal warning, so that the `apply` command doesn't abort?

(With this simple example, I could just remove the `nonexistent.txt` hunk from the patch file, but this isn't practical for a large patch where hundreds of hunks might need to be removed.)

## What I've tried

I've looked through the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply), but I can't find an option to do this.

The `--reject` option *"makes it apply the parts of the patch that are applicable, and leave the rejected hunks in corresponding *.rej files"*, but it's incompatible with the `--3way` option.

I've also tried `-C0` and `--unidiff-zero` (ignore all context).

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
git apply --verbose --3way --exclude=nonexistent.txt patch.txt
```